# How can I select an item from the div dropdown items?

Tags: python, selenium

[image]

```
self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "job_sector"))).click()  # job selector
        time.sleep(0.5)
        jobs = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("apz_typeahead__prediction_content")
        print(jobs)
        random.choice(jobs[3:]).click()
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Here is the code I am trying to select an item. But it doesn't work. Please help.
By the way other dropdowns has the same class. I am confused how can I distinguish different dropdown items. for every dropdown I want to select a random item.

Answer (score 0):

```
random.choice(jobs[3:]).click()
```

Starting after the 3rd index click the jobs from a random value after? It might need to scroll to as well.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", jobs[i])
```

**[:3] first 3 is this.**